# python: The correct way to assign a value from itertools.permutations()?

Tags: python

The following code creates a multi dimensional list (not sure if that's the Pythonic was of saying it. PHP guy here)

```
patterns.append(list(itertools.permutations('1234567',7)))
```

the value of patterns becomes:

```
([
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [1,2,3,4,5,7,6], ...

])
```

What I want is for the result to be like this:

```
([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,7,6]...)
```

If i try doing:

```
patterns = list(itertools.permutations('1234567',7))
```

the result is a list of individual numbers

```
123445671234576
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: I have tried this code and it gives me a list of tuples with string values inside.

Comment: so you want a tuple of lists instead of a list of lists?

Comment: I'm thinking that you want `patterns = tuple(list(p) for p in (itertools.permutations('1234567',7)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `extend()` instead of `append()`.

```
patterns.extend(itertools.permutations('1234567',7))
```

This also makes `list()` redundant because `extend()` works on iterables.

This assumes you are ok with the permutations themselves being tuples. Your question is confusing because you the notation doesn't correspond with what you wrote in words.

Comment: "notation doesnt correspond with what you wrote in words": I understand how that can be confusing. I'm still learning the Python lingo. I can update the question to make it less confusing for future explorers if you tell me what it should read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get

```
([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,7,6]...)
```

than you can use:

```
from itertools import permutations
patterns = tuple(list(int(y) for y in x) for x in permutations('1234567',7))
```

OR you can use xrange instead of '1234567' if you need to get numbers:

```
patterns = tuple(list(x) for x in permutations(xrange(1,8),7))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a tuple of lists with

```
tuple(list(p) for p in itertools.permutations('1234567', 7))
```

If you want integers instead of one-element strings, then an easy and general way to do that is

```
digits = [int(digit) for digit in '1234567']
tuple(list(p) for p in itertools.permutations(digits, 7))
```